# How to bind a list with one key and multiple values to a GridView or a Repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

[image]

and I am having a function to convert this list to a datatable

```
public static DataTable ConvertToDatatable<T>(IList<T> data)
        {
            PropertyDescriptorCollection props =
                TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T));
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            for (int i = 0; i < props.Count; i++)
            {
                PropertyDescriptor prop = props[i];
                table.Columns.Add(prop.Name, prop.PropertyType);
            }
            object[] values = new object[props.Count];
            foreach (T item in data)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
                {
                    values[i] = props[i].GetValue(item);
                }
                table.Rows.Add(values);
            }
            return table;
        }
```

what should I do to bind these multiple values to a repeater or a gridview

Comment: 1. Why do you need to create a DataTable, the original list will bind to Repeater/GridView by itself? 2. What have you tried to do to bind it?

Comment: binding the list to a repeater also wont work sice it having multiple values..... i need to view in my repeater both the key and  its corresponding values...

Comment: Here's a crazy idea for you, but if you flip the datasource so that the output binds your key as a column and your 35 values as rows, you will be able to bind it directly to the datasource of a gridview.
you are dejaggerfing it this way (that's my own made up word ;-)

Answer (score 4):

You can take repeater or gridview inside parent gridview or repeater.

for example:-

```
     Dictionary<int, object> g = new Dictionary<int, object>() { { 1, new { j = "g" } }, { 2, new { j = "ggfdf" } }, { 3, new { j = "gioret" } } };


  gridviewparent.DataSource= g.Select(h => new {key= h.Key});
  gridviewparent.DataBind();



  foreach (GridViewRow item in gridviewparent.Rows)
        {
         int key= Convert.Toint32( ((Label)item.FindControl("lblkey")).Text) ;
               GridView gridviewChild=(GridView)item.FindControl("gridviewchild");
            // return g[key]  in list
            gridviewChild.DataSource= g[key];
            gridviewChild.DataBind();

        }
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use a repeater inside a repeater. Here's how:

Convert your List into a `Dictionary<string, List<object>>` and store it into a Property (in my sample it is named `Dict`) that can be accessed by the .aspx file (at least `protected` or more accessible).
Then call `outerRepeater.DataBind()` at some point (For example in your `Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)` implementation).

Put this into your `.aspx` file to make it work:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="outerRepeater" DataSource='<%# Dict.Keys%>'>
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="innerRepeater" DataSource='<%# Dict[DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem").ToString()]%>'>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem")%>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</ItemTemplate>
```

You can use `<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.EventDate")%>` to access a Property (in this sample with the name `EventDate`) when you store concrete objects in the List inside the dictionary.
For example: `Dictionary<string, List<Event>>`

Answer (score 2):

I think the only thing you have to do here ,so as to bind the **dynamic** datatable to a gridView, is to use the build-in property of asp Gridview control **AutoGenerateColumns = "true";** unless you know exactly the columns you are up to bind so then you have to use a `GridView.RowDataBound Event`.

[What is exactly this AutoGenerateColumns property ?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.autogeneratecolumns(v=vs.110).aspx)

**~ ASP CODE**

```
<asp:GridView ID="MyGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns = "true" ></asp:GridView>
```

Suppose that `myDatatable` is the datatable object returned from your `ConvertToDatatable` method.
**~ C# Code:**

```
MyGridview.DataSource = myDatatable;            
MyGridview.DataBind();
```

Hope it helps!